# How do I manually change/update a user password in devise 3.2.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I tried to do this from my `seeds.rb`:

```
user = User.find_or_create_by email: ENV['ADMIN_EMAIL'].dup, password: ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD'].dup, password_confirmation: ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD'].dup
```

I am getting this error message:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.password does not exist
LINE 1: ...sers"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'abc@test.com' AND "users"."p...
```

I tried `encrypted_password`, but then I get the same for `users.encrypted_password_confirmation` does not exist.

Thoughts on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just go into the Rails console (`rails c`)

```
user = User.new(email: "myemail.com", password: "superSecret")
user.save
```

You can also change it

```
user = User.find_by_email("myemail.com")
user.password = "newSuperSecret"
user.save
```

EDIT:

I just put my first block of code in my `seed.rb` and ran `rake db:seed` with no problem. So I think the crux of your problem is just having the password attribute in your `find_or_create_by` call.  I think if you put this in your `seed.rb` you'll get the results you want (although I have to admit I'm not certain about the environment variables working, you might have to retool that portion of it).

```
user = User.find_or_create_by(email: ENV['ADMIN_EMAIL'].dup)
user.password = ENV['ADMIN_PASSWORD'].dup if user.encrypted_password.blank?
user.save!
```

Comment: I want to setup my `seeds.rb` file to create a new admin user for a vanilla version of the app.

Comment: You are right, I tried a variation of your first block before seeing your revised. Both will work. Thanks!