# How to manually save a new user from the rails console when using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an app with a single user, and want to clear the db and start again.

I saved the user table and cleared the db, and now want to create the single user in the new db.

I could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25539744/5783745):

```rb
user = User.new(
  email: "testm@example.com", 
  password: "1234",
  admin: false,
  time_zone: "International Date Line West",
  first_name: "testm",
  last_name: "testm"
  )
```

The problem is, I don't know their password (nor should I), and I can't figure out how to take their existing "encrypted_password" and insert it into the new database (I have the standard devise string that looks like so `"$2a$12$13Mu.SLk/M2KOFaqFkYAg.lTmq0mnqoWh6kL186yeK/yumS6C70HG"`)

How do I create a record and provide to it the devise string as the value for `encrypted_password`?

Note: attempting to add `encrypted_password: "$2a$12$13Mu.SLk/M2KOFaqFkYAg.lTmq0mnqoWh6kL186yeK/yumS6C70HG"` to the above simply results in:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password can't be blank
```

Comment: @RockwellRice thank you for the help. I have the old data as a csv. You're right, I just want to set up the user in the new (empty) database

Answer (score 0):

Running the same command *without* validations, and using `encrypted_password` instead of `password` seems to have worked:

```rb
user = User.new(
  email: "testm2@example.com", 
  encrypted_password: "$2a$12$MVR2XoDAAQVwRNsPT039K.MkEKXH5AhxpWafgiCQQM0o5wNXt6sVG",
  admin: false,
  time_zone: "International Date Line West",
  first_name: "testm",
  last_name: "testm"
  ).save!(validate: false)
```

I tested with a dummy account and the user can sign in successfully.

I am not sure if this could cause any other problems, so please use with caution (if others who know better than myself are aware of any problems this approach could cause, please comment)

**Another approach**

Another approach could be to not worry about invoking ActiveRecord objects, and instead interact with the database directly. For example via: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

#### Notes

With both methods, one thing to think about is if you have any callbacks after the save (e.g. via `after_save` or `before_save`), then it could be important to make sure those get called if it makes sense to do so